# Seekbar with Android 4.0 style

Tags: android, android-widget, seekbar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I know that it is possible to change the style of any widget in android.
However, i have try with the Seekbar.
I want to have seek bar like android 4.0 have. My app is running in android 2.2 and i want to show seekbar like Android 4.0.

So, what should to change?

I have try with below code:

```
 <style name="seekbarStyle" parent="android:Widget.SeekBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@android:drawable/progress_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@android:drawable/progress_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">20dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">20dip</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">@android:drawable/seek_thumb</item>
    <item name="android:thumbOffset">8dip</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>

</style>
```

Please help me. I want seekbar style to look like android 4.0 in all device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use HoloEverywhere library which allows to use Holo themes on Android 2.x

https://github.com/prototik/HoloEverywhere

Comment: Yes, but not automatically. You need to configure you app theme to inherit Holo.Theme

Comment: Please follow the link i posted, There you can find tutorial and beautiful demo

Answer (score 2):

As @user527759 mentioned `HoloEverywhere` can make your app to use Holo theme even in old Android versions. I want to show another option, because as you are asking in your question, how to make your `SeekBar` looks like in `Theme.Holo` . There are a few tools which I am using  almost everyday in my 'development life'  [Android-UI-Utils](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) . You can find lots of useful tools for styling `ActionBar`, `ActionBar Items`, `Generic Icons` and etc. And the thing which you need in is `http://android-holo-colors.com/` , which will create a theme for your applications with `Holo` colors for the UI elements which you will select before creating the theme.

The thing which I like about that is that you don't depend on another library (which is something which I prefer, at least for styling UI elements) and you can play with the colors. For example if your app's default color is red, you can set default color for `holo-colors`
 to be red too, so all your UI elements will have that color by default.

So this is just another option. I've never used `HoloEverywhere` , can't say anything about that library. It depends on you which path you will choose : )